# Dynamic styled-component tag name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm using [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) with [styled-icons](https://styled-icons.js.org/). I have:

```
import { Facebook } from 'styled-icons/feather/Facebook'
import { Twitter } from 'styled-icons/feather/Twitter'
import { Instagram } from 'styled-icons/feather/Instagram'

...

const FacebookIcon = styled(Facebook)`
  width: 10px;
  color: black;
`

const TwitterIcon = styled(Twitter)`
  width: 10px;
  color: black;
`

const InstagramIcon = styled(Instagram)`
  width: 10px;
  color: black;
`

...

render () {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <FacebookIcon />
      <TwitterIcon />
      <InstagramIcon />
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

**What would be a good way to DRY out this code?**

So I can use these icons like:
`<Icon name='Facebook' />`
or
`{ renderIcon(Facebook) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Facebook } from "styled-icons/feather/Facebook";

const IconWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 10px;
  color: black;
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <IconWrapper>
        <Facebook />
      </IconWrapper>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0oqlq6pq3l).